# No proper subgroup of finite index

Tags: group-theory

Show that $(\mathbb{Q},+)$, the group of rational numbers under addition, has no proper subgroup of finite index.

Can someone please provide a proof!

Comment: [A duplicate](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/182311/11619). Google *site: math.stackexchange.com Q has no subgroup of a finite index*. It isn't that difficult.