# Subgroup of $C^*$ (nonzero complex) with finite index.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

True or false:

Let $C^*$ be the set of all nonzero complex numbers and $H$ be a subgroup of $C^*$(with respect to multiplication) be such that $[C^*:H]$ is finite then $H=C^*$.

I'm guessing it true as I am thinking that if suppose there is such a proper subgroup $H$ for which the number of coset will be finite then I'm guessing that there is a gap between $C^*$ and $H$ and that gap cannot be filled up by finite union.  But I am unable to give a concrete prove.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Suppose $H$ has finite index in $\Bbb C^\times$, let $m=[\Bbb C^\times:H]$. Then for any nonzero complex number, $z^m\in H$. Now given $w\in\Bbb C$ we can always solve $z^m-w=0$, so $w\in H$.

Alternatively, a finite divisible abelian group is trivial. Now $\Bbb C^\times /H$ is finite, and it is divisible, so it must be trivial.

Comment: Why is $z^m \in H$? I don't follow that one step in this proof.

Comment: $(zH)^m=H$ as the order of the group ${gH: g\in C^*}$ is m. Now $(zH)^m = (z^m)H = H$, so $z^m \in H$.

Comment: The claim that a torsion divisible abelian group is trivial is blatantly false. However it holds that a finite divisible abelian group is trivial.

Comment: @YCor True, what I wanted to say is that finite (or torsion of finite index?) plus divisible implies trivial. An obvious counterexample is $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 4):

More generally, an (abelian) divisible group has no nontrivial subgroups of finite index. The proof is essentially the same as for [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/182311/subgroup-of-mathbbq-with-finite-index).