# Subgroup of $(\mathbb Q, +)$ with finite index

Tags: group-theory, proof-explanation

I don't understand a step in the proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/182315/66096)

Why must it be that $nq\in H$ ?

Comment: The [comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/182472/117818) in the link explains it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $G$ is a group of order $n$, then $g^n=1$, for every $g\in G$ (multiplicative notation).

If we apply this to the quotient group $G/H$, where $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ and $[G:H]=n$, then, for $g\in G$,
$$
H=(gH)^n=g^nH
$$
and so $g^n\in H$.

In additive notation, $ng\in H$.