# finite index of a group of rational number

Tags: group-theory

> Question:
>   Show that $\mathbb{Q}$ the group of rational numbers under addition has no proper subgroup of finite index.

I returned to an old exercise but couldn't go quite complete it, after looking at it for an hour.

Assume that $\mathbb{Q}$ has a proper subgroup H of finite index.
Then, let there be n distinct left coset of a proper subgroup H in G.
The left coset of H in G is of the form q + H, $\forall q \in \mathbb{Q}$

By a property of cosets, each elements q in $\mathbb{Q}$ is contained in one of $q_{i}$+H.

Here is where I tried to sought aid from the history but could not understand the argument behind nq $\in H$. How do we justify this fact?

[Subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}$ with finite index](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/182311/subgroup-of-mathbbq-with-finite-index)

Any help is appreciated. Thank in advance.

Comment: John Thompson proved this in detail in his answer at the duplicate.

Comment: If $[\mathbb{Q}: H]=n$, then the quotient group $\mathbb{Q}/H$ has order $n$. If $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ it follows that $n(q+H)=H$, i.e. $nq \in H$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde What is the motivation behind taking n-factors of the left coset q+H?

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi I am precisely having a difficult time following the fact that if q in Q, then n(q+H) =H, It is this subtlety that I am not understanding.

Comment: @Mathematicing The motivation comes directly from the question, i.e., that we have finite index $n$.

Comment: In an abelian group $G$ of order $n$, $ng=0$ for all $g \in G$. Apply this with $G=\mathbb{Q}/H$ and $g=q+H$.

Comment: It seems that n(q+H) is mean to show closure of sort; that the additive sum of all left cosets of H in G is H.

Comment: This is just the group law in the quotient group. It is a completely elementary argument.

Comment: @Mathematicing The key point here is that $\mathbb{Q}$ is divisible. Did you google "divisible" in wikipedia?

Comment: @Mathematicing Forget about cosets for a second. It follows from Lagrange's theorem that if $G$ is of order $n$ and $g\in G$ then $g^n=e$. Now in the language of abelian groups we use addition instead of multiplication and $0$ instead of $e$. So the same thing can be rephrased as $ng=0$. Now if you take $\mathbb{Q}/H$, which is abelian, then...?

Comment: Then the order of any elements in the factor group is n.@freakish
So, n(q+H)=0+H=H.

Comment: @Mathematicing The order of $\mathbb{Q}/H$ is $n$ by the assumption ($H$ is of the finite index $n$). So it follows that $nX=0$ in $\mathbb{Q}/H$ for any $X\in \mathbb{Q}/H$. Now $0$ in $\mathbb{Q}/H$ is simply $H$. And any element of $X\in\mathbb{Q}/H$ is of the form $X=q+H$. So all in all you get $n(q+H)=H$. This means $nq+H=H$ which is equivalent to (by the general property of cosets) to $nq\in H$.

Comment: Thanks I got it. The subtlety that the index of a subgroup H in a group G is just the order of the group G divided by its subgroup H is the order of the factor group is what was missing.