# Possible Properties of a Monotone Function

Tags: analysis

I'm working on the following question:

> Which of the following three properties imply $f$ is monotone (it maybe none or more than 1):
>
> 1. $f(x + y) = f(x)f(y)$
> 2. $f(x - y) = f(x)f(y)$
> 3. $f$ is periodic and non-decreasing.

I think 3 works, I'm not sure how to evaluate 1 and 2.

Comment: What do you mean by "monotonic"? A monotone function can mean a couple of things, but typically a function that is either non-increasing or non-decreasing, which would make 3 imply that $f$ is monotone trivially.

Comment: yes I meant monotone, I will change that

Comment: Also, what is the domain of $f$? I'm guessing $\mathbb{R}$ or $(0, \infty)$?

Comment: (3) implies that $f$ is constant

Comment: @TheoBendit yes, domain is all of $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) does not imply monotonicity. Take $g$ to be a discontinuous (also non-integrable, non-monotone) solution to [Cauchy's Functional Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation):
$$g(x + y) = g(x) + g(y).$$
Then $f = \exp \circ g$ is a non-monotone function satisfying
$$f(x + y) = f(x)f(y).$$

(2) For such a function $f$, first note that $f(0 - 0) = f(0)f(0)$, which implies $f(0) = 0$ or $f(0) = 1$. If $f(0) = 0$, then
$$0 = f(x - x) = f(x)f(x) \implies f(x) = 0$$
for all $x$, which tells us that $f$ is constant (and hence monotone). Otherwise, $f(0) = 1$, and similarly we see that $f(x) = \pm 1$ for all $x$. The only monotone functions possible are constant. So, the question is, are there any non-constant solutions?

Suppose $f$ is a non-zero solution. I claim that $f$ is a homomorphism from the group $(\mathbb{R}, +)$ into the group $(\{-1, 1\}, \cdot)$. If $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$, then
$$f(y) = f(x + y - x) = f(x + y)f(x) \implies f(x + y) = f(y) f(x)^{-1} = f(x) f(y).$$
If $f$ is not constantly $1$, then $f$ maps onto $\lbrace -1, 1\rbrace$, and $f^{-1}\lbrace 1 \rbrace$ is a group of index $2$ in $(\mathbb{R}, +)$, which [doesn't exist](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103262/is-there-a-proper-subgroup-h-of-mathbbr-such-that-mathbbrh-is). Thus, the only solutions are constant solutions $0$ and $1$, both of which are monotone. So **yes**, (2) implies monotonicity.

(3) This also implies monotonicity, as it specifies non-decreasing. Such functions are also constant, making me wonder if the question was about the functions being constant, not monotone?

Answer (score 1):

The first one should remind you of the exponential function $e^{x+y}=e^xe^y$, together with that, what are some things you must know about the function? What is $f(x+0)$? $f(x/2+x/2)$? $f(nx)$?

Is the second one even, odd, neither? What can be said about the shapes of such functions?

What family of functions does the third one belong to? How can something never decrease but still be periodic? This is a very strict requirement.

That should provide enough guidance to get you off the ground. Remember when posting questions in the future you are supposed to show that you've spent time researching it, and show your effort so far.

Good luck!

Comment: Could you elaborate on the second one? I did not think of the first example -- how did you see that?

Comment: You with with things a lot you develop intuition about it.

Comment: How are $f(x-y) $ and $f(y-x) $ related? What else can you say about the function? Try to play with some forms like I suggested for the first one. You gotta struggle through it to actually learn it!